# New features in CSLA 4.0 over CSLA 3.8

Tags: csla

What are new features in CSLA 4.0 over CSLA 3.8 and which one better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Change BusinessListBase/ReadOnlyListBase/etc to work with WPF (possibly creating a legacy set of collection types for Windows Forms)

  - Take advantage of the SL4/.NET 4 ability to have SL4 class libraries run in .NET 4
  - Improve the business rules subsystem, possibly also including the use of MEF to dynamically find/load rule methods
  - Support the .NET 4 client profile, also possibly split out interface layer functionality into separate projects
  - Rework LINQ to CSLA so creating a LinqBindingList is an explicit operation, not implicit and also so there's a LinqObservableCollection for use with WPF.
  - Remove the non-generic DataPortal methods, thereby removing the generic type parameter on SingleCriteria

Source ([forums.lhotka.net](http://forums.lhotka.net/forums/p/8037/38509.aspx#38509))

I know that CSLA 4.0 contains quite a few breaking changes for the better. The rules are getting a complete overhaul which was needed to support new scenarios.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))